# Search for Eliyahu Kitov source in Midrash (Bar Ilan search?)

Tags: midrash

Looking for someone who can search all midrashim/chazal/yalkut etc for original source
If I had otzar or bar ilan, I'd do it myself, using search words like I typed below from kitov's hebrew text. I'm assuming rabbi kitov didn't make it up, but culled it from some authentic midrashic source.

Here's loshon from Sefer Hatodaah:

ומה היא גבורתו שהיה יכול לעמוד ביסורים יותר מכל אדם שעל פני האדמה לכך נתנו הקב"ה באמצע הדורות שיהא נושא עליו כל הדורות שלפניו ושלאחריו עד שיגלה כל כחו לעת קץ הימים כקורה זו שנותנים אותה באמצעה של התקרה כדי שתעמיד את כל התקרה

Although it's also possible that it was indeed his own conclusion,, and if counting the "midpoint beam" from Dovid's birth, the Geulah would have been in the mems' (1984?), a year which would have sounded plenty futuristic and eschatological, from rabbi ki tov's perspective (like g orwell's lhavdil)

On page 142 of "The Book of our Heritage, Vol 3" by R. Eliyahu Kitov

[King] David however was the greatest hero of all the generations.
What was his strength, that he was able to withstand suffering more than any person on Earth?
G-d placed him at the midpoint of all the generations, so that he should be able to bear upon himself all the preceding generations and all those following till his power would be revealed at the End-of-Days -- like the center beam which holds aloft the entire ceiling.

Using this information, and the date of King David's birth of 2854 (from [*Chabad.org*](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/463958/jewish/David-the-Shepherd.htm) ) as well as the fact that he lived 70 years we take the midpoint of his life and double it to get the year of the Geulah:

( 2854+35) * 2 = 5778

Comment: As the Yiddish saying goes - די וואס ווייסט זאָגט ניט און די וואס זאָגט ווייסט ניט
Those that know, don't say and those that say, don't know!

Comment: I pulled random 3 word phrases from the Hebrew and ran them through Bar Ilan. Thus far, no hits.  The problem is that his paraphrasing might not reflect the actual language of the original.

Comment: I a not looking to calculate keitzim. Just searching for the midrash. Keep the thread focused please.

Comment: why do you assume its a midrash

Comment: Some versions (although I've never seen them) of Sefer todaah have sources incorporated in the text. does your version have them? If not, are you able to get a hold of one that does?

Comment: Yes, I just found out the sons of Ki Tov published versions with sources, but we don't have that version.

Comment: you may like this http://yeranenyaakov.blogspot.com/2014/09/5775-years-in-terms-of-77-generations.html?m=1

Comment: Did a Bar Ilan search. The best I could find was a very similar statement about Avraham in [Bereishit Rabbah 14.6](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.14.6?lang=he).

Comment: Probably not helpful, but I found the idea mentioned here as well: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01680.html -- Not sure who the author is, though